# Объявление переменных в pgsql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pgsql

Есть проблема с объявлением переменных в pgsql.

Вот рабочий вариант:

```
begin;
    @set a = 1
    select :a;  
rollback;
```

Вот вариант НЕ рабочий, который нужно сделать рабочим:

```
begin;
    @set a = 1
    @set b = :a --ошибка синтаксиса ":" (я так понимаю распознает всё как текст)
    select :b;  
rollback;
```

Перерыл варианты, не получилось. Если подскажете, как можно решить эту проблему, буду признателен

1. не могу использовать do + declare, т.к. внутри перестают работать функции расширения, которые находятся в другой схеме
2. не могу использовать \s, т.к. не в терминале

Comment: Это что за синтаксис такой интересный? Ты уверен, что это Postgres, а не, например, какой-то sql клиент тебе помогает?

Comment: вот тут посмотри правильный синтаксис для Postgres https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/plpgsql-declarations.html

Comment: или вот тут примеры получше https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/plpgsql-variables/

Comment: @AlexanderPavlov спустя много часов оказалось, что это синтаксис dbeaver, а не, непосредственно, постгреса. Нашёл вариант решения проблемы из bash-скрипта таким же заданием переменных не через @ set, а через -v в вызове. Но предпочёл вариант всё переиграть и сделать через do + declare. Спасибо за ответы :)